# How to get user agent on load function in SvelteKit

Tags: svelte, svelte-component, sveltekit

I want to get the `user agent` on the `load function` to choose whether to perform server-side rendering or not depending on the visitor is `googlebot` or not.

How can I access it inside the `load function`?

I'm using the latest version of SvelteKit which is 1.0.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Managed it using hooks.

Create `hooks.js` inside `src` folder:

```js
export function getSession(request) {
    return {
        userAgent: request.headers['user-agent']
    }
}
```

Then you can use it inside `load function` of each component you want:

```
<script context="module">
    export async function load({ session }) {
        console.log(session.userAgent)
    }
</script>
```

See hooks section for more information in [docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks).

Comment: No need to use hooks for this purpose since request object is available to the load function by default, i.e. you could use load({ request }) instead of session and proceed.

Comment: Anyway to make this typescript friendly?

Answer (score 1):

Not allowed to comment yet but load({ request }) worked for me:

```
/** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */
export async function load({ request }) {
    const headers = request.headers;
    const userAgent = headers.get('user-agent');
    console.log('User agent:', userAgent);
}
```

JSDoc import makes it typescript-friendly, for Oliver Dixon

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Note that this only works in +page.server.js, not +page.js