# How to execute code on SvelteKit app start up

Tags: sveltekit

I have a SvelteKit based application in development. On the server startup, be it on a development server boot up, Node.js adapter boot up I would like to execute some diagnostics commands. An example of such action is to ping the backend server and fail early if the backend is unreachable. This would be mostly a concern for server-side rendering, but if it is easy I would like to apply it for static deployments as well.

What would be the best hook to place in such code?

Also what would be graceful way to abort the application launch with an error message?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm looking to do the same thing. If I find an answer, I'll post it here.

Comment: I did not find any smart solution yet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The accepted answer does not answer the question. Server hooks are run once per request or per error. They are not associated with server lifecycle, and are not an appropriate place to, for example, initialize a database or preload site-wide data. Looking now for a way to do just that.

https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks

My guess is that the answer is somewhere in one or more of the adapters used.

Comment: you may want to ask your question in the discord channel: https://svelte.dev/chat

Comment: Solved. See my answer below

Answer (score 8):

By now, there finally seems to be an official answer:

https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks

> Hooks
>
> [...]
>
> There are two hooks files, both optional:
>
> - src/hooks.server.js — your app's server hooks
> - src/hooks.client.js — your app's client hooks
>
> **Code in these modules will run when the application starts up, making them useful for initializing database clients and so on.**
>
> [...]

So yes, just put your code in one of the hook.js-files (a top level, not in a function), and it runs at startup.

Edit: As tried out by leumasme (https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/927#issuecomment-1349637401) this only applies to release builds though. In dev mode the code gets executed only with the first request. So keep this in mind.

Answer (score 8):

Solved by a Svelte Ambassador {} pablopang at Svelte's Discord channel. Quote:

```
if you run the code inside the module of hooks.server.ts 
it will be exected only once
what i mean is that you need to run right inside hooks.server.ts 
not in the exported handle function

obviosuly be aware of the fact that if you deploy on serverless 
every new lambda spin up will run that code 
but that should be good since it's like if you just spun up the server
```

Answer (score 4):

There are correct answers provided, but I wanted to give an example of how it works. Simply put the code you want to execute on server startup in `src/hooks.server.js`

For example

```js
import * as db from '$lib/server/database';
console.log("Startup sequence initiated.");
db.load(); // this line will be executed only once during server startup
console.log("Startup sequence complete.");
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this can be done with hooks.
This is from an example on a question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66945320/how-to-get-user-agent-on-load-function-in-sveltekit), that would get the user agent on page load.

Create `hooks.js` inside your `src` folder:

```js
export function getSession(request) {
    return {
        userAgent: request.headers['user-agent']
    }
}
```

Then you can use it inside the `load` function of each component you want:

```html
<script context="module">
    export async function load({ session }) {
        console.log(session.userAgent)
    }
</script>
```